# Exclude BuildConfig.class and R.class from Android library jar in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When building an Android Library Project with Gradle, what's the correct way to exclude BuildConfig.class   and R.class  from the resulting .jar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a custom task:

```
task androidReleaseJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: assembleRelease) {
    from "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release/"
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
    exclude '**/R.class'
    exclude '**/R$*.class'
}
```

Reference:
1.https://github.com/facebook/rebound/blob/master/build.gradle
2.https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/blob/master/library/build.gradle
3.https://github.com/SnowdreamFramework/android-log/commit/4297a0244c972e3fcb9042b5e12181b21c33b524

Answer (score 8):

Probably the most elegant solution is to add at the end of the library's `build.gradle`:

```
afterEvaluate {
    generateReleaseBuildConfig.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To excude R and BuildConfig use this

```
afterEvaluate {
    generateReleaseBuildConfig.enabled = false
    generateDebugBuildConfig.enabled = false
    generateReleaseResValues.enabled = false
    generateDebugResValues.enabled = false
}
```

Don't forget to clean the project before building

Answer (score 4):

you should get it right after the CompileReleaseSources step.

this worked for me:

```
task removeBuildConfig(dependsOn: "compileReleaseSources") {
    doFirst {
        file("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release/pathToFile/BuildConfig.class").delete()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
afterEvaluate {
    bundleDebug.dependsOn "removeBuildConfigDebug"
    bundleRelease.dependsOn "removeBuildConfigRelease"
}

task removeBuildConfigDebug(dependsOn: "generateDebugBuildConfig") {
    doFirst {
        file("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug/com/amazon/geo/routing/BuildConfig.class").delete()
        file("$buildDir/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/amazon/geo/routing/BuildConfig.java").delete()
    }
} 

task removeBuildConfigRelease(dependsOn: "generateReleaseBuildConfig") {
    doFirst {
        file("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release/com/amazon/geo/routing/BuildConfig.class").delete()
        file("$buildDir/generated/source/buildConfig/release/com/amazon/geo/routing/BuildConfig.java").delete()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, when bundle task added, we can hook it here.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded {
    if (it.name == 'bundleRelease' || it.name == 'bundleDebug') {
        // bundle task is Zip
        it.exclude '**/BuildConfig.class', '**/R.class', '**/R$*.class'
    }
}
```